# Table error causing excessive runtime

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx, makecell

I tried to write a table, but I cannot find what is wrong with it as it is preventing my file from compiling:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 Material & $\Xi$ & 
 \makecell{ $\Sigma_{a}$ \\ [1/m] }
 & \makecell{ Macroscopic Slowing \\ Down Power(MSDP)} 
 & Moderating Ratio(MR) & 
 \makecell{ Elastic scattering mean free path \\ MFP\textsubscript{ela} [cm] } \\[0.5ex] 
 \hline
 \ce{H2O}(l)      & 0.927 & 2.226 & 1.425 & 62 & 0.66\\
 \hline
 \ce{D2O}(l)      & 0.510 & 0.001 & 0.177 & 4830 & 2.77\\
 \hline
 \ce{Be}          & 0.207 & 0.094 & 0.154 & 126  & 1.29\\
 \hline
 Graphite(\ce{C}) & 0.158 & 0.030 & 0.083 & 216  & 2.50\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Moderating properties of materials}
\label{table:3}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about the error(s) you're getting. Please also state which document class you employ and which packages need to be loaded in order to have a chance to compile your code.

Comment: There is no explicit error message given in the log files, however the compiler runs on indefinitely(i.e. more than 20 minutes without succeeding) when I try to compile the code section listed above.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in nice @Mico answer (+1), source of your problem is use square brackets inside  `\makecell` command. Using here they should be enclosed by curly braces.

With `tabularray` package and use of the `booktabs` and `siunitx` libraries (which load packages of the same name), your table can be written as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Moderating properties of materials},
  label = {table:3},
note{a} = {MSDP: Macroscopic Slowing Down Power},
note{b} = {MR: Moderating Ratio},
note{c} = {MFP: Mean Free Path}
                ]{
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        colspec = {@{} l *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=1.3}]}
                       X[c, si={table-format=4.0}]
                       X[3, c, si={table-format=1.2}]
                   @{}}
                 }
    \toprule
Material
    & $\Xi$
        & {{{$\Sigma_{a}$ \\ {[\unit{1\per\meter}]}}}}
            & {{{MSDP}}}\TblrNote{a}
                & {{{MR}}}\TblrNote{b}
                   & {{{Elastic scattering 
                      MFP\textsubscript{ela}\TblrNote{c}\quad 
                      {[\unit{\centi\meter}]} }}}  \\
    \midrule
\ce{H2O} [\unit{\liter}] & 0.927 & 2.226 & 1.425 &   62 & 0.66\\
\ce{D2O} [\unit{\liter}] & 0.510 & 0.001 & 0.177 & 4830 & 2.77\\
\ce{Be}                  & 0.207 & 0.094 & 0.154 &  126 & 1.29\\
Graphite (\ce{C})        & 0.158 & 0.030 & 0.083 &  216 & 2.50\\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
added is note to last column.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe the immediate source of the problem is the line

```
\makecell{ $\Sigma_{a}$ \\ [1/m] }
```

By default, LaTeX interprets anything enclosed in square brackets that follows a `\\` directive as a directive for supplemental vertical spacing; for this to work, the entity in square brackets has to evaluate to a length, e.g., `1ex`. That's obviously not the correct interpretation here. To inform LaTeX about this, you need to change the expression shown above to

```
\makecell{ $\Sigma_{a}$ \\ {} [1/m] }  % note the '{}' particle
```

In addition to fixing this issue, you should also make some changes to the layout to guarantee that the tabular material actually fits within the width of the text block. Specifically, I believe you need to allow line breaking in columns 4 thru 6. In the first table below, I employ a `tabularx` environment and centered versions of the `X` column type to accomplish this goal.

To further streamline and simplify the look of the table, I'd like to suggest you employ the acronyms MSDP, MR, and MFP directly, without accompanying definitions, in the header cells. (Hopefully, you will have introduced these acronyms to your readers by the time they get to the table.) That'll allow the table's width to shrink considerably. See the second table below for an illustration.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem,makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l cc C S[table-format=4.0] C @{}} 
 \toprule
 Material 
 & $\Xi$ 
 & \makecell[t]{$\Sigma_{a}$ \\ {} [\unit{1\per\meter}]}
 & Macroscopic Slowing Down Power (MSDP)
 & \mC{Moderating Ratio (MR)}
 & Elastic scattering mean free path MFP\textsubscript{ela} [\unit{\centi\meter}]  \\
 \midrule
 \ce{H2O} [\unit{\liter}] & 0.927 & 2.226 & 1.425 &   62 & 0.66\\
 \ce{D2O} [\unit{\liter}] & 0.510 & 0.001 & 0.177 & 4830 & 2.77\\
 \ce{Be}                  & 0.207 & 0.094 & 0.154 &  126 & 1.29\\
 Graphite (\ce{C})        & 0.158 & 0.030 & 0.083 &  216 & 2.50\\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \caption{Moderating properties of materials}
\label{table:3}

 \bigskip\bigskip
 \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} % return to default

 \begin{tabular}{@{} l ccc S[table-format=4.0] c @{}} 
 \toprule
 Material 
 & $\Xi$ 
 & \makecell[t]{$\Sigma_{a}$ \\ {} [\unit{1\per\meter}]}
 & MSDP
 & {MR}
 & \makecell[t]{Elastic scattering \\ MFP\textsubscript{ela} [\unit{\centi\meter}]}  \\
 \midrule
 \ce{H2O} [\unit{\liter}] & 0.927 & 2.226 & 1.425 &   62 & 0.66\\
 \ce{D2O} [\unit{\liter}] & 0.510 & 0.001 & 0.177 & 4830 & 2.77\\
 \ce{Be}                  & 0.207 & 0.094 & 0.154 &  126 & 1.29\\
 Graphite (\ce{C})        & 0.158 & 0.030 & 0.083 &  216 & 2.50\\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Moderating properties of materials, 2nd version}
\label{table:3a}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: "I believe you need to allow line breaking in columns 4 thru 6." Could you specify which part of the code allows for this? I thought this might be useful because I find myself have to line-break cells quite often

Comment: @YingXiangTow - In the first table, it's the `C` column type (note the use of an uppercase letter) that allows automatic line breaking in columns 4 thru 6. (For col. 5, the `C` column type is imposed just for the header cell, via `\mC{...}`.) The `C` column type is defined in the preamble: `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}`. The `C` col. type is a centered version of the `X` column type which, in turn, is a variant of the basic-LaTeX `p` column type. For more information about the `X` column type, please see the user guide of the [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package.